# emacs smart html syntax highlighting

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, elisp, xhtml

Is there a syntax highlighting mode for xml/html which supports highilghting of markup associated with given (just like for parentheses)? For example if I select 'div' markup - this 'div'  and corresponding with it '/div' are highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Install this minor mode - https://github.com/deactivated/hl-tags-mode

Also check this page on EmacsWiki - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HtmlMode - there are plenty of links on Emacs+HTML capabilities.